# C# Obeying the NewLine Character in a String Pulled from SQL server

Tags: c#, string, newline

All (this is back-to-basics!), I have a string of information I am pulling from SQL Server. The string is something like

```
Hello, my name is Frank Butcher\n\n
and I work at Watford Car lot, 
and I am 65 years old.
```

The message is to be pulled into a message box to provide information on a process. I read the string using

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
cmd.CommandText = strSQL;
strResult = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

this gets the string, but when I put this into my text box the message is displayed with `\n\n` not with the required double NewLine.

I have tried using

```
strResult = strResult.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);
```

on the string but this does not help. Am I going mental, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: did you try with strProcessDetails = strProcessDetails.Replace(@"\n", Environment.NewLine); NOTE THE @ before the string

Comment: This would also have worked. Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am assuming you have stored a literal backslash then the character "n" in the string in the database, and not a newline character. Thus you have to do the `String.Replace` which you are doing.

You are *so* close, but you need to escape your backslash:

```
strResult = strResult.Replace("\\n", Environment.NewLine);
```

Without escaping the backslash, the compiler is interpreting the `\n` to be a special escape sequence for a newline, so your line becomes the equivalent of "replace NewLine with NewLine" (which you have figured out does nothing).

Alternatively, you can prefix the string constant with an `@` symbol, meaning to treat it as a literal:

```
strResult = strResult.Replace(@"\n", Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Sometimes all it takes is another pair of eyes. I've added a little explanation for anyone else who happens to come here.