# Character encoding when retrieving from database

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have a WPF MVVM application which stores some text in a database (nvarchar). This text includes `\n` to indicate a new line. When I view the column in SQL Management Studio, it displays `\n` as expected but when the data is being retrieved using Entity Framework, it brings back `\\n` which causes the newline not to be displayed when I'm binding the property to my textblock.

How can I stop this behaviour?

**Some additional information:**
The text comes back from the DB and gets assigned to a property on the viewmodel which is then bound to the textblock. If I hardcode the property to be something like "Time\nStamp", it works perfectly with the textblock displaying the data on 2 separate lines. The problem only seems to lie in Entity or the DB. I'm using SQL server 2012 btw.

Comment: I'm confused. It goes in as `\n`, shows up as `\n` and retrieved as `\n`. I don't get what you're asking. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Sorry, fixed. just noticed that StackOverflow also want to be helpful and add unwanted formatting for me.

Comment: Do you display your data directly? or do you do something with it first?

Comment: Check the TextWrapping.  Default is none.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.textwrapping.aspx  Is suspect the \\n is just escaping it for you.

Comment: Edited my question with some additional information. TextWrapping is on and I don't do anything else to the data, it just gets put straight onto the viewmodel.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11453016/1466627).

Comment: A reach and only a comment.  If it is in SQL has \r\n does it work?

Comment: @Bob Thanks, `Replace("\\n",Environment.NewLine)` did the trick. If you can put that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [C# Obeying the NewLine Character in a String Pulled from SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453016/c-sharp-obeying-the-newline-character-in-a-string-pulled-from-sql-server), when you retrieve a string from SQL, the value stored in the database is stored as a literal. When the `\n` is retrieved, it is read into the string value as a literal, and not a New Line escape character.

```
 str.Replace("\\n", Environment.NewLine); // Changes the escaped new line character to a NewLine character, environmental dependent.
```