# Serialize object with newline character in string property gets undesirably escaped

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, json.net

This question has nothing to do with the suggested [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729811/json-net-unexpected-characters-when-serializing-my-entities). The answer for that specific question is that the debugger in Visual Studio escapes JSON strings. I already outruled this by writing the actual value to a file. I also specifically mention that I use the *Text Visualizer* tool in Visual Studio which does not have this issue!

### Problem description:

I have a SQL table Descriptions:

| Id | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello \n world |

I retrieve the table using Linq:

```
var result = _dbContext.Descriptions.Single(x => x.Id == 1);
```

Looking at the value of `result.Description` in the *Text Visualizer* we see that it has the expected value "Hello \n world".

Now I serialize the object using Newtonsoft without specifying serialization settings:

```
var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

Looking at the value of `serialized` in the *Text Visualizer* we see that we now have the following JSON string:

```
{ "Id": 1, Description: "Hello \\n world" }
```

As we can see it has escaped the newline character (\n) by adding an extra backslash. I need the serialized JSON to not add this extra backslash escape character as shown here:

```
{ "Id": 1, Description: "Hello \n world" }
```

### Thoughts and experiments

1. Both the escaped and unescaped JSON string seem to be valid when using some online JSON validators.
2. Using the following code results in the wanted serialized output, but it's hardcoded and not fetched from the database:

```
var result = new
{
    Id = 1,
    Description = "Hello \n world"
};

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

3. When using the hardcoded example above but instead of using a regular string we use a verbatim literal, we get the same undesired result:

```
var result = new
{
    Id = 1,
    Description = @"Hello \n world"
};

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

4. Looking at the JsonSerializerOptions that we can use I see there is an option specify the `StringEscapeHandling`. But it seems that all possible values include escaping of control characters (e.g. newline).

### Roundup

How can I prevent escaping the newline character? I'd rather not resort to substring replacement strategies.

Comment: are you positive you want that? seems like it is invalid json what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/are-multi-line-strings-allowed-in-json

Comment: @RandRandom, I'm not sure if the question you refered to is specific for Python. I used multiple online and offline JSON validators and they all agree that using the unescaped version is valid JSON. If you could point me to a resource that clearly states that the wanted JSON result is invalid I would change my approach. But for now I just don't understand what is happening. Also, if it was invalid JSON, why would experiment 2 result in the wanted JSON result? I would expect Newtonsoft not to serialize into invalid JSONs.

Comment: @JKL I can not see any problem. As a matter of fact  when I serialize it I have only one \.  But what is the problem in any case? Do you an expected error or what? What is the difference for you how many slashes? What is the pourpose of your question?

Comment: @Serge I think it's obvious that OP wants this string to be rendered somewhere else with a newline character and not with a literal "\n" in-between.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Do you mean to print it and to put on a wall?  What is the pourpose of this except to start world  from the new line?

Comment: @Serge are you really questioning the business value of a minimally working example? Is it so hard to imagine a multiline description for whatever OP is working on?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride You will not believe me, but a couple of years ago I didn't have any idea how a json string looks. I serialized and deserialize c# data for more than 10 years  and didn't care what is inside, slashes or dotes or something else.

Comment: What exactly are you storing in the database? An actual newline character or the escape sequence "\n"? This might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847847/character-encoding-when-retrieving-from-database

Comment: @Serge, as already mentioned by GoodNightNerdPride, what I want is to display this string in a HTML page with newline character, see CSS [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#values).

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride, thank you for this link. I cannot believe I haven't found this SO question before with the key words I used. What is mentioned in your provided link explains what we're seeing in nr. 2 and 3 of my experiments. So strings fetched from SQL server are interpreted as verbatim literal strings, just as in experiment 3 (see the @ character). I wonder if there is a way to interpret it as a regular string. Using the suggested replace strategy is not optimal since I'll be having a large list of these objects to serialize.